# Un équivalent français de « self-indulgent »

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Je cherche une bonne traduction de l'adjectif anglais *self-indulgent*, dans un contexte un peu particulier : par exemple, tel qu'on pourrait l'utiliser pour décrire un artiste (musicien ou autre) *ou sa performance* dont l'art n'est pas vraiment digne des compliments qu'il reçoit (impliquant une certaine complaisance du public).

Les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés me semblent tout à fait à côté de la plaque, avec: *jouisseur* voire *complaisant* (l'inverse de la situation présente).

J'ai pensé à *nombriliste*, qui me semble le plus proche de la situation sus-décrite, mais n'évoque pas suffisamment à mon goût l'aspect « qui se fait plus plaisir qu'aux autres » (un peu *jouisseur*, justement, mais pas que).

Est-ce que quelqu'un aurait une suggestion pour un terme plus approprié ?

Comment: C'est marrant, parce qu'à ma connaissance *self-indulgent* n'a pas vraiment ce sens en anglais (c'est plutôt « qui ne fait que ce qu'il a envie »), et je le traduirais plutôt par *hédoniste…* Mais comme ce site n'est [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/) et que ce n'est pas ce que tu cherches, j'en fais un commentaire `:)`

Comment: @F'x: je suis d'accord que le sens premier est plus celui de 'hédoniste'... c'est pour ça que je précise. Dire d'une performance artistique qu'elle est 'self-indulgent' parait tout à fait naturel à mon oreille (et je suis sûr de l'avoir déjà lu/entendu chez d'autres anglophones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je te proposerais bien

> narcissique

J'avais pensé également à *égocentrique* mais il manque (à mon goût) la notion de l'amour pour soi, le « je m'aime ! » :D

Answer (score 11):

Je dirais *[suffisant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suffisant/adjectif)* ou *[imbu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/imbu/adjectif) de sa personne*.

Les synonymes donnés sur la page page de *suffisant* sont aussi intéressants, surtout *[fat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fat/adjectif)* dont la définition correspond bien à ce que tu demandes : *médiocre mais très satisfait de soi*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour les suggestions: c'était assez dur de choisir entre celle-ci et la réponse de Cédric. Néanmoins, même si j'aime bien 'fat', je pense qu'au final 'narcissique' est un peu plus proche.

Comment: Si vous vous demandez, apparemment *fat* se prononce [fat].

Answer (score 5):

Il y a bien des mots qui gravitent autour de cette attitude, je n'en vois pas qui seraient plus adaptés aux artistes même si je pense justement à quelques artistes dans ce cas.
Je proposerais donc *suffisant*, *[vain](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vain)*, *[présomptueux](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9somptueux)* et *fat* qui a déjà été proposé mais qui est moins courant.

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que dans le sens de complaisance du public il y a **succès d'estime**.

Le [TLFI](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/search.exe?73;s=3425923470;cat=1;m=succ%8As+d%27+estime;) donne comme sens à cette expression : *Succès limité, sans enthousiasme, obtenu par exemple dans un cercle restreint de connaisseurs ou d'amateurs.*

Toutefois, cette expression n'a pas toujours un sens péjoratif : lorsque le cercle restreint comporte vraiment des connaisseurs, alors le succès d'estime peut avoir une grande valeur.

Answer (score 0):

Si c'est le public qui est *self-indulgent* alors l'artiste sera *surcoté*, *fanatisé*, la critique dithyrambique sera *complaisante*.
D'autres qualificatifs sont possibles selon le contexte.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, mais je pense que tu confonds un public *indulgent* et *self-indulgent*. Dans tous les cas, il s'agit de l'artiste (et de sa performance), pas du public...